# Axios returns 500 error while request returns the response

Tags: javascript, axios, requestjs

I have call an API from my `javascript` code using the `requests` package. But since it is deprecated, I want to replace it with `axios`.

The call is like this:

```
request({
  url: 'the_url',
  method: 'POST',
  encoding: null,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-protobuf',
    'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
  },
  body: requestBody,
}, callback);
```

Where the `requestBody` is `Uint8Array` I create with the data I need to send. The above works ok and I get the response I need. However, when I re-write this to `axios` like this

```
axios({
    url: 'the_url',
    method: 'POST',
    encoding: null,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-protobuf',       
      'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
    },
    data: requestBody,
  }
).then( (res) => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch( (error) => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

The server returns a 500 error. It is the exact same URL and same `requestBody` variable.

EDIT: When I inspect the actual request objects for both cases, it looks the passed `requestBody` doesn't have the exact same format.

In the case of `request`, it is like this:

`body: <Buffer 22 07 ... ... 396 more bytes>`

But in case of `axios` like this

```
data: ArrayBuffer {
  [Uint8Contents]: <22 07 ... ... 346 more bytes>,
  byteLength: 446
}
```

Nothing changes in the creation of the `requestBody`. I pass exactly the same parameter in both cases. So, it has to be something related to how `axios` and `requests` handle those cases.

Comment: What is in `requestBody`? Is it an object, or is it a JSON string / stringified object?

Comment: It is a protobuf, serialised object in the format of `Uint8Array`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let formData = new FormData()

formdata.append('reqBody', requestBody)

axios({
    url: 'the_url',
    method: 'POST',
    encoding: null,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',       
      'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
    },
    data: formdata,
  }
).then( (res) => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch( (error) => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: Getting this `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: source.on is not a function` which Google says you get when the FormData is not an object :(